# Cannot generate RSA private Key on Android

Tags: java, android, cryptography, rsa

I have a PEM RSA private key and read it from the hard-cord string.
It works on Android below 4.3 but does not work on Android 4.4 and 5.

In Android 4.4 above, I get the error.

```
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(KeyFactorySpi.java:105)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:186)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.getFakePrivateKey(CharonVpnService.java:1984)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.getUserKey(CharonVpnService.java:1346)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454): Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at java.math.NativeBN.BN_new(Native Method)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at java.math.BigInt.makeValid(BigInt.java:51)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at java.math.BigInt.putBigEndianTwosComplement(BigInt.java:181)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:304)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERInteger.getValue(DERInteger.java:90)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.<init>(PrivateKeyInfo.java:79)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(PrivateKeyInfo.java:45)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(KeyFactorySpi.java:91)
-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):  ... 4 more
01-08 11:49:31.004: E/CharonVpnService(31454): ##########################################################
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.getFakePrivateKey(CharonVpnService.java:1998)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.getUserKey(CharonVpnService.java:1346)
01-08 11:49:31.004: W/System.err(31454):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Here is my snipped code to generate private key.

```
 private static String privateKey =
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"+
"MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAl+rYuFTZkztxypSrmvUaq0haVYtiadD2XOpBdGn5RW5eQ8yn\n"+
"cTBynw7TXTH4OF31fkdqjvuDQ8rom4M5O7i6KvQkcCzlnnPgJJeN6VrBU3JfLHVb\n"+
"poFqnyzY/WhB6kkfHwFADiaFscjZuLJPIR1VR2RzCMjehlkx5rDYMle3/wYu0sSS\n"+
"SpZsERZ4wzh2TweCJfM2mskBnRA+5RADaOGnMlALRI+OFEj8Wo+ZodjUOQdoeOIe\n"+
"XiceytCE4goSrdTc/IPhT+C3G2dctOni3zbc3Dpi1Rm9bcxezOMCQb0c8Jrssf6B\n"+
"aO/CfleZVe4X8SDZD20jRvW4oTAZu1fnw9kPywIDAQABAoIBACxDUefLWSWL4WjM\n"+
"Dn/0wFN9nkxkc0UvjEigPHgF1IpFURPiEjtpiUwMzsrNn2wU/E1R05tbbvCWs1V0\n"+
"U32yIhQX1HIWssSLMJiYy9FdDw0YOuDCRPTrqjw8nfCfquzvZzDqdVZqJPQa+EzX\n"+
"LzUPzeQiQV4i4Ks2W9LCXgu1ATg9iwEguRbePKAZ4wmiHScYp9LkwHXpkJYdPAFh\n"+
"8J96aGFVs8nwEJBFMXdrhgCqlbKNJjXNxriLtqf/nBsiqzDxk8UNx5+EGfB99b1U\n"+
"v7UlcGKHwTdxz9bKrNE8S3R28dGdskG8lZinSBkNI4koA01Os41VH7nMjxFHuARr\n"+
"VixKcdkCgYEAyLAJa4+83c8H3q4Mqmepxvtvbix+YHelU3G6kLvC5Fgf3WV/+PPE\n"+
"TiDyzAfBFELGQGmi7+Nb/Y+4+j7h2rfafaS/JeBVtSABQydW5CW0KWm6KgJn98NT\n"+
"z0gDMVRSVJDrwpRjeUYThnz2M4FnOAGbc08EZi+qiTJv8jIifAH7eL0CgYEAwcm2\n"+
"7N9MUsuFn9BTbe8JjUSK82Pmqa1WMQJlmldG5w2/w0Q3TLoDqJKXs/PUOqT1aX+A\n"+
"OT2qrtlhduSLWz0rod8gyVx7gOiCnNcoIU1DZqr0U7NgSF9mdBcZYAGkdE56AkPp\n"+
"GCCK5krONjFA2H2az008qCMue8JDdIdM2Qo2hycCgYBqpCiNUJcS4rWS3bf7QRSV\n"+
"mPxwdhI9nrZqbe+ugyegATgFhK8JEjfJMHb0dlZiNs10Yu3jPVSfm6S2zX1kpPfk\n"+
"dgvgy6Gfmr8w+RGSMHrY2sbDFf47ST8a0XBo4R7SsyOkhQeK5PLxLywA2I2J1EjP\n"+
"cDitOD0NpJCaCYwLi14enQKBgGYGlVBQoBZXIJrrS4FtgFHn7GAIEMD0iZRz9poz\n"+
"qRisnHFp0NOMe7CcvVH45ZuajbplblS0qtAzkqTN3rDCm941Y0Wgc0WDJID+phoi\n"+
"W4IKL2iB4Ac6cu5b2vg45SR2zLW0m1wghgCJEdhmRgW023SY7X54R1jRBkKrmUIL\n"+
"pnmxAoGBAJ2JKeBs2sigZJB4q673orZq1OdPh4EpjO3nViq/SMF2RvOc4VY694SC\n"+
"LbLbIppDu1+cp+kUL2bf+rgH1fZZ3+L1hpxayr20VGXym+icZIDBImcgIlHWsNVF\n"+
"ti05osMkCYF9vByldjLtCQUtxowUdsf1ZpF5Zyy7tsn5Mlr8Xdxz" ;
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";


private PrivateKey getFakePrivateKey(){
    PrivateKey fakePriKey =null;        
    byte[] encoded; 
    KeyFactory kf;
    String privKeyPEM = privateKey.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    try {
       encoded = Base64.decode(privKeyPEM.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT);
       EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new  PKCS8EncodedKeySpec( encoded );
    kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        fakePriKey = (PrivateKey)kf.generatePrivate ( keySpec );
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fakePriKey;
}
```

The stronger stuff is that work on Android 4.3 below. I have no idea about what's happening and not working on Android 4.4 above. 
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: I was wondering why I didn't take a look at this question, but if you don't include any tags that indicate cryptography then people will miss the question completely on this site; the amount of questions is just to large to view them all. Anyway, a *very* belated welcome; see this as a newbe error, given enough tags SO works a lot better.

Comment: This stack trace is very weird. It doesn't look like a normal stack trace. It is missing the initial exception and I'm wondering if the order is correct.

Comment: This should not be needed: `privKeyPEM.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")`; Base64 is *supposed to be* printable characters instead of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

use this code. now i test it and work well.I use it in Android studio

```
public static PrivateKey stringtoprivatekey(String privateKeyString)
    {

        try {
            if (privateKeyString.contains("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----") || privateKeyString.contains("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"))
                privateKeyString = privateKeyString.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            if (privateKeyString.contains("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----") || privateKeyString.contains("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"))
                privateKeyString = privateKeyString.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

            privateKeyString = privateKeyString.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
            byte[] privateKeyDER = Base64.decode(privateKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyDER));
            return privateKey;

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```