# How to store RSA Private Key on android app

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, keystore

I did look at this post: [Cannot generate RSA private Key on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834366/cannot-generate-rsa-private-key-on-android) but it did not work for me.

My idea is to encrypt an access token using RSA encryption and store the Private key on the device. I have successfully encrypted the token using RSA but i am lost as to where the best place to store this key is. I tried storing it using KeyStore, however i do not know enough about this to debug as to why it is not working. Keep getting a Error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: no match.

My keys do match, but again, no idea whats wrong as i do not know enough about this. I was using setEntry and storing the private key in weird and wonderful ways which im sure, if it worked would not have been the same key when it was returned.

What is the best way to store this Private Key and where???

I am no security expert so any advice on this will be appreciated as well as if i should rather use AES?

My code is below, I am only using 1 activity.

```
package com.example.rsatest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter;
import java.security.KeyStore.PasswordProtection;
import java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter;
import java.security.KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.DropBoxManager.Entry;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String keyStoreFile;
Key privateKey = null;
boolean isUnlocked = false;
KeyStore keyStore = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    keyStoreFile = this.getFilesDir() + "/bpstore.keystore";
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.credentials.UNLOCK"));
            isUnlocked = true;
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.android.credentials.UNLOCK"));
            isUnlocked = true;
        }
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "No UNLOCK activity: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        isUnlocked = false;
    }

    if(isUnlocked){
        privateKey = GetPrivateKey();

        try{
            char[] pw =("123").toCharArray();
            keyStore = createKeyStore(this,keyStoreFile, pw);
            PasswordProtection keyPassword = new PasswordProtection("pw-secret".toCharArray());

            SecretKey sk = new SecretKey() {

                @Override
                public String getFormat() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return privateKey.getFormat();
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getEncoded() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return privateKey.getEncoded();
                }

                @Override
                public String getAlgorithm() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return privateKey.getAlgorithm();
                }
            };
            System.out.println(sk.getEncoded());
            System.out.println(privateKey.getEncoded());
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ent = new SecretKeyEntry(sk);
            keyStore.setEntry("pk", ent, keyPassword);
            keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile), pw);

            KeyStore keyStore2;
            keyStore2 = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            keyStore2.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile), pw);
            KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore2.getEntry("pk", keyPassword);
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entOut = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)entry;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
        }

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private KeyStore createKeyStore(Context context, String fileName, char[] pw) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("[DIR]:" + fileName);
    File file = new File(fileName);

    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

    if (file.exists()) 
    {
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), pw);
    } else 
    {
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(fileName), pw);
    }

    return keyStore;
}

private Key GetPrivateKey(){
    String theTestText = "This is just a simple test!";

    Key publicKey = null;

    Key privateKey = null;
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "RSA key pair error");
    }

    // Encode the original data with RSA private key
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        encodedBytes = c.doFinal(theTestText.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "RSA encryption error");
    }

    // Decode the encoded data with RSA public key
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(encodedBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "RSA decryption error");
    }
    return privateKey;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Warren

Comment: That other post was a pretty specific error. It didn't have the correct tags so everybody missed it. About your code; why are you trying to store an asymmetric key as a symmetric key (`SecretKey`)? That will certainly not work. Note that the Java keystore interface is pretty much aimed at storing keys + certificates. You may want to use another storing method for just RSA private keys (e.g. wrap them yourself using `Cipher`).

Comment: Thank you Maarten, much appreciated. I will take a look at wrapping it with cipher and see what i can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to add RSA private key to the keystore we ended up using AES instead and wrap it using cipher. We have also included ProGuard for our Android project to make it harder to decompile our APK.

Thank you Maarten Bodewes for your answer and help.

> That other post was a pretty specific error. It didn't have the correct tags so everybody missed it. About your code; why are you trying to store an asymmetric key as a symmetric key (SecretKey)? That will certainly not work. Note that the Java keystore interface is pretty much aimed at storing keys + certificates. You may want to use another storing method for just RSA private keys (e.g. wrap them yourself using Cipher).